# How to set rgba channel values of image in Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a PNG image with the colors white and green with transparency. I want to make it like in Team Fortress 2 where you can set the RGBA values like this:

Set RGBA to (255,255,0,1) to make the white parts turn yellow
Set RGBA to (255,0,0,1) to make the white parts turn red and the green parts black

Comment: I don't know what a Team Fortress 2 is, sorry. You say you want to make the white parts yellow. Then you want to make the white parts red. Is it an animation where the white parts are yellow at one time and red at another? Please click [edit] and clarify. Thank you.

Comment: i guess he’s trying to describe color multiplication

Comment: Very confusing request. Please clarify and show examples of what you have and what you want.